# Finding the first pair of maximal sum by indices in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, indices

I have a code in which I have to print the first pair of indices of the maximal sum between two arrays of the same length. The first value i from arr1 and the second value j from arr2. I succeeded to find the pairs of values and its indices which have the maximal value of 7 (there're two pairs of sum of 7). But I just need the first pair of the maximal sum to be printed which is the closest to the first element of the array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class maximal_sum
{
    static void kLargestPair(int[] arr1, int n1, int[] arr2, int n2, int k)
    {
        if (k > n1*n2)
        {
            System.out.print("k pairs don't exist");
            return ;
        }

        int index2[] = new int[n1];

        while (k > 0)
        {
            int max_sum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            int max_index = 0;

            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < n1; i1++)
            {
                if (index2[i1] < n2 &&
                        arr1[i1] + arr2[index2[i1]] > max_sum)
                {
                    max_index = i1;

                    max_sum = arr1[i1] + arr2[index2[i1]];
                    List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<int[]>();

                    result.add(new int[]{arr1[max_index],arr2[index2[max_index]]});

                    if(index2[max_index] > max_index) {

                        System.out.print("(" + arr1[max_index] + ", " +
                                arr2[index2[max_index]] + ") "); 
                        //here prints the pair of values: (6,1) (4,3)
                        //we just need to print (4,3) because it comes before (6,1) according to the indices

                        System.out.print("(" + max_index + ", " +
                                index2[max_index] + ") ");
                       //here prints the pair of indices: (2,3) (0,1)
                       //we just need to print (0,1) because it comes before (2,3) according to the indices

                    }


                }
            }

            index2[max_index]++;
            k--;
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr1 = {4, -8, 6, 0};
        int n1 = arr1.length;

        int[] arr2 = {-10 ,3, 1, 1};
        int n2 = arr2.length;

        int k = 6;
        kLargestPair( arr1, n1, arr2, n2, k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to print out the biggest value while looping and why you loop six times (k = 6) and not only four times (i.e. the length of the arrays). I do not understand your use of `k`, what is it's intent?

To better structure your code start by looping through every possible number combination between your arrays and calculate the sum. Store a reference to the biggest sum and the associated index. After the calculation simple print the biggest sum with the index. This has to be done AFTER all calculations are done.

In code:

```
static void kLargestPair(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
   int biggestSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //storing reference to biggest sum
   int biggestIndexArr1; //storing reference to biggest index in arr1
   int biggestIndexArr2; //storing reference to biggest index in arr2
   int currentSum; //stroing reference to current calculated sum for the current calculation

   for(int indexArr1 = 0; indexArr1 < arr1.length; indexArr1++) { //Nested for loops to calculate every possible sum in the two arrays
      for(int indexArr2 = 0; indexArr2 < arr2.length; indexArr2++) {
         currentSum = arr1[indexArr1] + arr2[indexArr2]; //calculate current sum
         if(currentSum > biggestSum) { //By only checking > instead of >= only the first encounter of the biggest sum will be stored (getting a sum as big as the current biggest sum will not store)
             biggestSum = currentSum;
             biggestIndexArr1 = indexArr1;
             biggestIndexArr2 = indexArr2;
         }
      }
   } 
   System.out.println("Biggest sum is " + biggestSum + " at index (" + biggestIndexArr1 + "," + biggestIndexArr2 + ")");
}

public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        int[] arr1 = {4, -8, 6, 0};
        int[] arr2 = {-10 ,3, 1, 1};   
        kLargestPair( arr1, arr2);
    }
```